# Neo4j - APOC procedure do not import all of my data

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have a problem using apoc procedure apoc.import.json.
It does not import all of the data of my json file.
The report of the procedure shows around 60 000 nodes and 400 000 relationships.

[image: Result of the import procedure]

[image: Number of nodes insde the database]

The number of nodes is correct, but when I count the number of relationships, there are only 17 410...

[image: Number of relations inside the database]

Does anyone encounter this problem ?

My neo4j database is a 4.2.2 version.

Thanks

Comment: I would post this as an issue directly top APOC repo: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures

Comment: What happens if you remove the outgoing arrow: `p=()-[]-()` ?